# Fatal error at provisioning while installing python

Tags: python, ansible, provisioning

I have this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  pre_tasks:
    - name: 'install python2'
      raw: sudo apt-get -y install python-simplejson
  roles:
    - git
    ...
```

Sometimes, it works perfectly fine and sometimes it gives me this error:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i '/var/www/test/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key' -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --extra-vars="ansible_ssh_user='ubuntu'" --limit="all" --inventory-file=ansible/hosts/hosts_linux.txt -v ansible/site.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [install python2] *********************************************************
fatal: [10.0.11.44]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "rc": 255, "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.0.11.44                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

I am wondering why do I get this error and what does it mean? There is no output on the error and the exactly same code works if I try this many times. It makes no sense. Why is ansible failing to install python?

Comment: What is the ansible version? Did you try to run ansible-playbook with -vvvv option to get more debug informations?

Comment: It asks this:  The authenticity of host '10.0.11.44 (10.0.11.44)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:OdyB21PWYP5NqgU6MfaV5Gr82tWsZxCg+juGVGub62M.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Comment: After that I get many errors ending with Trying private key: /home/calinpristavu/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/calinpristavu/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password)

Comment: so, there's your error. It isn't installing python that's the problem.

Comment: I am aware of that, yes. And the reason has something to do with the ssh connection and the private keys but I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, the problem is with ssh. You can create your own ansible.cfg file in your current working directory and supply openssh options directly as described here: [open-ssh options](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#openssh-specific-settings)

I suggest you try:

```
 [defaults]
 host_key_checking = False
```

And also during your playbook run, you can manually specify which ssh key to use like:

```
ansible-playbook --private-key /path/to/ssh_key ...
```

Finally, make sure there is no IP conflict, because your server's ssh fingerprint should not change. Try manually ssh'ing a few times as well.

Comment: Yep. You were right with the last one. There was an IP conflict with some other configuration I previously had. All I had to do was change the IP and it worked. I was interested more in making the provisioning work, not in provisioning a specific IP address. I must have got it all wrong with the IP addresses and that was the issue. Thank you!